# Is there TTL feature in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I checked Memgraph docs and I did not find TTL (time to live) or expiration time on node creation feature available. Did I just miss it and it exists, or there is no such feature in Memgraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this feature does not exist in Memgraph, but there is an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/856) regarding this, that represents a feature request. Adding a comment there would help Memgraph developers better prioritize.